# How to know the file upload duration within a Spring Rest Controller

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, kotlin

I need the ability know the duration of a file upload within a @PostMapping method in a @RestController.

So far I've had no luck.

I thought of using HttpServerletRequest.getDateHeader() but this obviously isn't server time and isn't trustworthy.

```
fun receiveFile(@RequestParam("file") file: MultipartFile, request: HttpServletRequest){
    ...
}
```

Comment: you can add a custom filter that starts a timer, and end it within your controller

Comment: Have you checked out https://www.baeldung.com/spring-performance-logging already?

Comment: Eventually it turned out that I didn't need to do it, but my workaround for the time being was obtaining the raw HttpServletRequest and using ServletFileUpload to get access to the stream and timing it manually. Do not recommend.